# Plotting the longest eligible period from an array in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I have an array of 31 periods and a function they go through.

I'm trying to write a script that would PLOT the longest period that is above 0.9 (given the function). Additionally, if the longest period is "maxed out", it should plot in a different color. If none are above 0.9, it should calculate an additional 14 period that is not part of the array and decide whether it will be plotted or not.

The function part is working well, no problem there. But I'm having trouble coming up with a cycle and the plotting itself. The code is below. There must be an error starting at the `//31-period array` line and onward. Can anyone point out the mistake(s) to me, please?

You can omit the part from `//*Start of the WAVE-PM function` to `//*End of the WAVE-PM function`, as I'm certain those calculations are correct.

Any support is welcomed. Thank You.

```
//@version=4
study(title="14-600 LOXP Wave-PM", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2000)
////////////////////////////////////
//*Start of the WAVE-PM function
////////////////////////////////////
LengthBandsShift = 0
LengthBandsDeviations = 1.25
Chars = 100
MathTanh(x)=>
    exp=0.0
    returnNum=0.0
    if (x>0)
        exp:= exp(-2*x)
        returnNum := (1-exp)/(1+exp)
    else
        exp:=exp(2*x)
        returnNum:=(exp-1)/(1+exp)
    R=returnNum
WAVEPM(BandPeriod,BandDeviations,Chars,Shift)=>
    avg = sma(close,BandPeriod)[Shift]
    sum=0.0
    for j=1 to BandPeriod-1
        temp = close[j] - avg
        sum := sum + temp * temp
    ShortDev= BandDeviations * sqrt(sum / BandPeriod)
    ShortDev1 = pow((ShortDev /0.0001), 2)
    temp= sum( ShortDev1,Chars)
    temp := sqrt(temp / Chars) * 0.0001
    if (temp != 0)
        temp := ShortDev / temp
    return=temp//ShortOscillator = MathTanh(temp)
////////////////////////////////////
//*End of the WAVE-PM function
////////////////////////////////////

//31-period array
int[] periods = array.new_int(31)
array.set(periods, 0, 600)
array.set(periods, 1, 500)
array.set(periods, 2, 450)
array.set(periods, 3, 400)
array.set(periods, 4, 350)
array.set(periods, 5, 300)
array.set(periods, 6, 275)
array.set(periods, 7, 250)
array.set(periods, 8, 225)
array.set(periods, 9, 200)
array.set(periods, 10, 180)
array.set(periods, 11, 160)
array.set(periods, 12, 140)
array.set(periods, 13, 125)
array.set(periods, 14, 110)
array.set(periods, 15, 100)
array.set(periods, 16, 90)
array.set(periods, 17, 80)
array.set(periods, 18, 70)
array.set(periods, 19, 60)
array.set(periods, 20, 55)
array.set(periods, 21, 50)
array.set(periods, 22, 45)
array.set(periods, 23, 40)
array.set(periods, 24, 36)
array.set(periods, 25, 32)
array.set(periods, 26, 28)
array.set(periods, 27, 24)
array.set(periods, 28, 20)
array.set(periods, 29, 18)
array.set(periods, 30, 16)

//Longest Over-Expanded Period, i.e. above 0.9
int loxp = na
//Boolean used later at the 14 period. Default set to false.
bool noPeriod = false
//If the longest period in the array (600) is not below 1.0, then set the loxp to 600 but plot it in a different color
bool overflow = (MathTanh(WAVEPM(600,LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)) < 1.0)
if overflow==false
    loxp:=600
//If the 600 period is not "overflowed", cycle the array and find the highest period above 0.9
else
    for int i = 0 to 30
        PeriodValue=(MathTanh(WAVEPM(array.get(periods, i),LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)))
        if PeriodValue >= 0.9
            loxp:=array.get(periods, i)
            break
    
    //Additionally count the 14 period (not itself in the array) if none of the previous periods are above 0.9.
    //If this period is under 0.9, change the boolean noPeriod to true. If this boolean is true, DO NOT plot anything.
    if (MathTanh(WAVEPM(14,LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)) >= 0.9)
        loxp:=14
    else
        loxp:=1
        noPeriod=true
   
//Plot the longest period above 0.9 AND its Bollinger Band set to 1.25 standard deviation. 
mult = 1.25
basis = sma(close, loxp)
dev = mult * stdev(close, loxp)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
//If the 600 period is overflowed, plot in #FF9800
basisColor = overflow ? #E040FB : #FF9800
backgroundColor = overflow ? #311B92 : #FF9800
bandColor = overflow ? #311B92 : #FF9800
//If the boolean noPeriod is true, avoid plotting anything, otherwise plot
plot(basis, "Basis", color=basisColor, transp=noPeriod ? 0 : 100)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=bandColor, transp=noPeriod ? 0 : 100)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=bandColor, transp=noPeriod ? 0 : 100)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=backgroundColor, transp=noPeriod ? 0 : 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you closer to what you seem to be looking for:

- The array initialization only occurs on the first bar. It's more efficient.
- You were always overriding the value of `loxp` determined in the loop in the `if` statement following the loop. We enclosed that inside another `if` that only executes if no `loxp` value was set in the loop.
- We now handle the dynamic transparency with the `color` parameter in plots, as `transp` doesn't allow for "series int", so can't vary bar to bar.

```
//@version=4
study(title="14-600 LOXP Wave-PM", overlay=true, max_bars_back=2000)
////////////////////////////////////
//*Start of the WAVE-PM function
////////////////////////////////////
LengthBandsShift = 0
LengthBandsDeviations = 1.25
Chars = 100
MathTanh(x)=>
    exp=0.0
    returnNum=0.0
    if (x>0)
        exp:= exp(-2*x)
        returnNum := (1-exp)/(1+exp)
    else
        exp:=exp(2*x)
        returnNum:=(exp-1)/(1+exp)
    R=returnNum
WAVEPM(BandPeriod,BandDeviations,Chars,Shift)=>
    avg = sma(close,BandPeriod)[Shift]
    sum=0.0
    for j=1 to BandPeriod-1
        temp = close[j] - avg
        sum := sum + temp * temp
    ShortDev= BandDeviations * sqrt(sum / BandPeriod)
    ShortDev1 = pow((ShortDev /0.0001), 2)
    temp= sum( ShortDev1,Chars)
    temp := sqrt(temp / Chars) * 0.0001
    if (temp != 0)
        temp := ShortDev / temp
    return=temp//ShortOscillator = MathTanh(temp)
////////////////////////////////////
//*End of the WAVE-PM function
////////////////////////////////////

//31-period array
var int[] periods = array.new_int(31)
if barstate.isfirst
    array.set(periods, 0, 600)
    array.set(periods, 1, 500)
    array.set(periods, 2, 450)
    array.set(periods, 3, 400)
    array.set(periods, 4, 350)
    array.set(periods, 5, 300)
    array.set(periods, 6, 275)
    array.set(periods, 7, 250)
    array.set(periods, 8, 225)
    array.set(periods, 9, 200)
    array.set(periods, 10, 180)
    array.set(periods, 11, 160)
    array.set(periods, 12, 140)
    array.set(periods, 13, 125)
    array.set(periods, 14, 110)
    array.set(periods, 15, 100)
    array.set(periods, 16, 90)
    array.set(periods, 17, 80)
    array.set(periods, 18, 70)
    array.set(periods, 19, 60)
    array.set(periods, 20, 55)
    array.set(periods, 21, 50)
    array.set(periods, 22, 45)
    array.set(periods, 23, 40)
    array.set(periods, 24, 36)
    array.set(periods, 25, 32)
    array.set(periods, 26, 28)
    array.set(periods, 27, 24)
    array.set(periods, 28, 20)
    array.set(periods, 29, 18)
    array.set(periods, 30, 16)

//Longest Over-Expanded Period, i.e. above 0.9
int loxp = na
//Boolean used later at the 14 period. Default set to false.
bool noPeriod = false
//If the longest period in the array (600) is not below 1.0, then set the loxp to 600 but plot it in a different color
bool overflow = (MathTanh(WAVEPM(600,LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)) < 1.0)
if overflow==false
    loxp:=600
//If the 600 period is not "overflowed", cycle the array and find the highest period above 0.9
else
    for int i = 0 to 30
        PeriodValue=(MathTanh(WAVEPM(array.get(periods, i),LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)))
        if PeriodValue >= 0.9
            loxp:=array.get(periods, i)
            break
    //Additionally count the 14 period (not itself in the array) if none of the previous periods are above 0.9.
    //If this period is under 0.9, change the boolean noPeriod to true. If this boolean is true, DO NOT plot anything.
    if na(loxp)
        if (MathTanh(WAVEPM(14,LengthBandsDeviations,Chars,LengthBandsShift)) >= 0.9)
            loxp:=14
        else
            loxp:=1
            noPeriod:=true
   
//Plot the longest period above 0.9 AND its Bollinger Band set to 1.25 standard deviation. 
mult = 1.25
basis = sma(close, loxp)
dev = mult * stdev(close, loxp)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
//If the 600 period is overflowed, plot in #FF9800
basisColor = overflow ? #E040FB : #FF9800
backgroundColor = overflow ? #311B92ff : #FF9800ff
bandColor = overflow ? #311B92 : #FF9800
//If the boolean noPeriod is true, avoid plotting anything, otherwise plot
plot(basis, "Basis", color=noPeriod ? basisColor : na)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=noPeriod ? bandColor : na)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=noPeriod ? bandColor : na)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=noPeriod ? backgroundColor : na)

// Debugging.
plotchar(loxp, "loxp", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(overflow, "overflow", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(noPeriod, "noPeriod", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```